# Можно ли закрепить элемент не по верхнему краю, а по нижнему, чтобы он рос вверх на нужную высоту?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

Всегда используется атрибуты top и left, которыe задают верхнюю точку левую точку элемента. А если известно, где должна быть нижняя левая точка или нижняя правая точка, а размеры неизвестны, то можно как-нибудь закрепить положение нижней точки, чтобы элемент отрисовывался вверх от нее на нужную высоту? Ну и влево на нужную ширину, если это правая точка?

Comment: @Helena2977, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Bottom и right
Высоту менять с помощью height.

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/position //  position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось с позицией.